# How can I create a details box with text and dividers in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, frameworks, flutter-layout

I wanna achieve this:

[image: what i need]

I'm new on Flutter and I'm trying do design some UI to learn; reading the documentation I was thinking of achieving this by using [Column](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout) and [Dividers](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html) but I don't know how to change the style of the column with rounded borders, background color and things like that + I don't know which widget should I use for the text. Can anyone help me please and maybe show me some examples?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `Column` widget, you can achieve the UI design by using the `Card`, `ListView`, and `ListTile` widgets.

- [Card](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html) - Provide the rounded border for its child.
- [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) - Load the widgets as scrollable based on scroll direction.
- [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) - A build-in child widget for the ListView.

Find the code snippet below.

```
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.25),
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Title'),
            subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Title'),
            subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Title'),
            subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Title'),
            subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Title'),
            subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Title'),
            subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Title'),
            subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks almost what I needed, i tried it out but I get the error "RenderBox was not laid out". I made a small research and tried to add shrinkWrap: true in the ListView. It works but list is not scrollabale anymore. Suggestions?

Comment: I just added the ListTile widgets for fill with in the screen height. If you want to make it scrollable, you can add more ListTile widgets to inside the ListView.children property..